# Is there a way to launch a standard Salesforce Send Email User Interface from LWC or Aura or VF?

Tags: lightning-web-components, send-email

Is there a way to launch a standard Salesforce Send Email User Interface from LWC or Aura or VF?

I need to build an LWC component with an option to launch a standard Salesforce Send Email User Interface.

So far, I don't see any options for this.

There is no component neither in LWC Library nor in Aura Library which does that, also, there is no method, interface or component which supports this.